# How to set alarm for every 10 minutes in Android Application?

Tags: android, alarm

Hai am trying to set alarm for every 10 minutes.But its running first time only any Body kindly help me

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectionReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1 * 1000),   pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//every 10 minutes i want to print the toast
```

Comment: replace (1 * 1000) by (10 * 60 * 1000) where you set for alarmManager in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use alarmManager.setRepeating method

follow this link on developer site

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Answer (score 2):

```
    Calendar calCurrent = Calendar.getInstance();
    long tenmin = 10 * 60 * 1000;
    int mynotifyidis = Integer.parseInt(mydelid);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService1.class);
    mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mIntent.putExtra("id", mynotifyidis);

    AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent snoozependingintent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
            -mynotifyidis, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calCurrent.getTimeInMillis() + fivemin, fivemin,
            snoozependingintent);
```